# Check if users in a csv are part of an email group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv of SamAccountNames that I need to check are in a certain group. So far I have this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Import-Csv -path C:\path\to\csv
$group = "groupname"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive |
             Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
ForEach ($user in $users) {
    If ($members -contains $user) {
        Write-Host $user
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Not in group"
    }
}
```

The output is only giving me "Not in group" for every entry even though I know there are some.

Comment: Make sure your $Members variable contains results. Does it ? If so, look at the variable content using $Members | FL . You will see that it returns an object and not just a bunch of SAMAccount names. You'd need to do a piping to Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName to get just an array with SamAccountName. Then you might be able to get results in your ForEach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) cmdlet outputs *custom objects* whose *properties* correspond to the input CSV file's *column values*.

Therefore, your `$users` variable by definition does *not* contain SAM account names *directly*, it contains custom *objects* one of whose *properties* contains the value of interest.

For instance, if `C:\path\to\csv` contained something like:

```
SamAccountName,More,Stuff
user1,foo,bar
user2,baz,bam
...
```

your conditional would have to be:

```
if ($member -contains $user.SamAccountName) { # ...
```

If your CSV file lacks a header row or is just a plain-text file with an (implied) single column of values, you can specify one with `-Header`; e.g., if `C:\path\to\csv` contains only:

```
user1
user2
...
```

you could use `$users = Import-Csv -LiteralPath C:\path\to\csv -Header SamAccountName` and use the same conditional as above, or, more simply, if there's just a single column, use
`$users = Get-Content C:\path\to\csv` to read the lines into an array and use your original conditional.